# Advantages of different Java type erasures and generic type formats

Tags: java, templates, generics, types

I am implementing a library in Java the uses generics. According to my understanding, generic types were introduced later in Java to provide a feature similar to templates in C++, while also maintaining backwards compatibility. That being said, the parameterized type `AVLTree<K, V>` at runtime simply appears as
`AVLTree`, hence the name "Type Erasure."

I have found the following three ways of writing my class definition to be equivalent in that the compiler does not complain, nor do I get any strange runtime issues related to types. I am not using reflection, so I have not seen a benefit in that area.

I've been told NOT to use this:

```
AVLTree<K extends Comparable<K>, V>
```

Instead they say, USE this:

```
AVLTree<K extends Object & Comparable<? super K>, V>
```

But, the following is also okay:

```
AVLTree<K extends Comparable<? super K>, V>
```

I have read that if you can avoid using `SomeClass<E>` you should, and newer Java is using this syntax `<?>.` Can someone please clarify the difference and the impact that this has on my code? Am I potentially introducing a bug if I am not consistent?

Comment: I'd say that `K extends Comparable<? super K>` is correct.  `Object` is unnecessary and implied (always).  `Comaparble<X>` won't actually compile for some classes (if `Comparable` is actually implemented on a super class of `X`).  But otherwise your question is very broad and should probably be broken down into smaller, better focused questions.

Comment: As I understand it, the reason that some methods (e.g. `Collections.max()`) have the extra `Object &` bound, is because (in the case of `Collections.max()`) the pre-generics version of this method had return type `Object`, and they need the generics version of the method to have the same runtime signature, so they need the erasure of `T` to be `Object` and not `Comparable`. Adding the extra `Object` bound first causes the erasure to be `Object` and not `Comparable`. Arguably, the pre-generics version should have returned `Comparable`, but they didn't, so they are stuck with that.

Comment: But unless you are worried about signature compatibility with a previous version of your library, or something like that, I don't see any reason why you would add a redundant `Object &` bound.

Comment: @newacct That's a good point. With that in mind, I'll omit it because I am using objects that absolutely require the erasure to be Comparable - example AVLTree, RedBlackTree where I need to order values. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, *they* should argue their decision (or invite them here, it's always a good option). Strictly speaking they do make sense, but not that much.

The declaration `AVLTree<K extends Comparable<? super K>, V>` means that you can compare children via parents (via `? super K`). For example `? extends CharSequence`, you can compare *any* `CharSequence`, not just `String` for example. These are the standard declaration under [the famous PECS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/what-is-pecs-producer-extends-consumer-super).

To be honest I rarely have to do this (may be I'm not exposing my API too often), so I usually do:

```
K extends Comparable<K>
```

This way you would not introduce any bugs, you will just limit the api's that can be called, obviously if you care about this.

On the other hand `<?>` is not newer or older syntax, it simply says *any type*, well you rarely want that IMO. Declaring such a `List<?>` for example, will make it read only and the objects you are going to get from it are `Object` only, this is just a shorter version of `? extends Object`.

Comment: "so I usually do: K extends Comparable<K>" `K extends Comparable<? super K>` is definitely better. For example, suppose you have a class `Animal` that is comparable to itself (implements `Comparable<Animal>`). And `Dog` is a subclass of `Animal`, and you have a list of `Dog`s. Any `Dog` is comparable to any other `Dog` (`oneDog.compareTo(anotherDog`) compiles and works), but `Dog` does not (and can't) implement `Comparable<Dog>`. A `K extends Comparable<K>` bound does not work for `Dog`, but a `K extends Comparable<? super K>` bound does.